# Facebook comment iframe height, tried FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() and FB.Canvas.setSize()

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have Facebook comments on [this](http://blap.kodingen.com/e3radio/) page.

I've set max comments to 5, for some reason the iframe height is set with an inline style of 662px regardless of trying to override it with `.Canvas.setSize()` or `.Canvas.AutoGrow()`.

Occasionally the height corrects itself to 249px (based on 2 comments) after a Facebook authentication. Could it be something to do with being in a hidden div when the FB `innt` callback is fired?

Any insight or work arounds?

Comment: hmmm, 662px is suspiciously the height viewport onload. I'm thinking I may set the #app div outside the title safe area ( position: absolute; left: -10000px ) until the intro animation is complete, and then remove those styles. It doesn't seem that lazy loading is an option as the FB.init() has to fire to check login onload.

Comment: fixed :D seems the comment box has unpredictable behaviour if instantiated in a hidden element

Comment: Please delete your question if you've solved the issue.

Comment: No dont delete your question but post an answer your self. This is helpful as I had a similar issue when angular hides a view.